# Parenthisis error while trying to create IN query dynamically in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Trying to create a select query in Pl/sql in sql developer , have to prompt the surname variable in oracle sql developer and will get the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t1.fullname, t2.salary
FROM TABLE1 t1  
JOIN TABLE2 t2  ON t1.ID = t2.employeeID
WHERE t1.city = 'denver' 
AND t1.surname IN ( select REPLACE ( &surname, ',' , ''',''' ) from dual )
AND t2.payment = 'cheque';
```

&surname will be input example -

```
'KAHN,GIGGS,BANKS'
```

it will become `'KAHN','GIGGS','BANKS'`

but its giving error as `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

If its cant be achieved in this way , please suggest any other way  but in that way , I have to use the &surname variable , so that it can be input to the query

Comment: The result of applying `REPLACE` to a string is again a single string (in your case, one that has embedded single-quotes, as literal characters); it is not a comma-separated list of multiple "simple" strings. What you want to do can't be done that way. It can be done in other ways, all of them more complicated than that.

Comment: can you please suggest any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using like instead of in?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t1.fullname, t2.salary
FROM TABLE1 t1  
JOIN TABLE2 t2  ON t1.ID = t2.employeeID
WHERE t1.city = 'denver' 
AND &surname like '%'||t1.surname||'%'
AND t2.payment = 'cheque';
```

Bobby

Comment: its giving error as ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Try including single quotes around the values you pass into &surname. 'KAHN,GIGGS,BANKS' works but KAHN,GIGGS,BANKS gives an ORA-00920.

Comment: thanks it worked with variable too , thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this (it's reproducible in SQL Developer):

```
create table t1 (surname) as
select trim (column_value) from xmlTable ('"KAHN","GIGGS","BANKS"')
/
define surname='KAHN,GIGGS,BANKS'

select * 
from t1
where surname in (
    select trim (column_value) 
    from xmlTable(('"'||replace ('&surname',',','","')||'"'))
    )
/
```

Outcome:

```
SURNAME
--------
KAHN
GIGGS
BANKS
```

Comment: getting error like 
ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: 
XVM-01003: [XPST0003] Syntax error at 'KAHN'
1   ''KAHN,'GIGGS'
-    ^
my input was 'KAHN,GIGGS' when using a variable like :surname

Comment: You should try it exactly as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the this `select REPLACE ( &surname, ',' , ''',''' ) from dual` result?
it will be a string like `'KAHN','GIGGS','BANKS'` and that's just a value, not a list.

**one way is bellow:**

```
with t(res,lev) as (
               select trim(regexp_substr(:surname,'[^,]+', 1, 1 )) res, 1 as lev
                 from dual
                where regexp_substr(:surname, '[^,]+', 1, 1) is not null
                union all           
                select trim(regexp_substr(:surname,'[^,]+', 1, lev+1) ) res,  lev+1 as lev
                  from t
                  where regexp_substr(:surname, '[^,]+', 1, lev+1) is not null
            )
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.fullname, t2.salary
    FROM TABLE1 t1  
    JOIN TABLE2 t2  ON t1.ID = t2.employeeID
    WHERE t1.city = 'denver' 
    AND t1.surname IN ( 
      select res
          from t
    )
    AND t2.payment = 'cheque';
```

You should enter in prompt this : `KAHN,GIGGS,BANKS`

Comment: both the solutions are giving me error as ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: ok I got the issue , it works if I hardcode the surname in , but if I use parameter/variable , its not working , I have to use &surname variable , so that it can be an input to the query

Comment: now the query is building fine , but with proper input its not giving any result , query is giving zero record

Comment: I hardcoded the input its working , if i put the same value when variable prompt for :surname  , its giving 0 result - no compile error